# How to override the language with apex:outputText for date formatting?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) the outputText component is locale sensitive and can even override the language by setting the `lang` attribute.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, EEEE}" lang="da">
  <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

The above snippet, however, will always print the English name for the current day of week, for instance the expected output with Danish language is `tirsdag` but outputText prints `Tuesday` instead.

This applies also without using the `lang` override and instead setting the language on the user.

How can I make outputText respect the `lang` attribute? Or at least follow the user language?

P.S. A similar problem occurs with number formatting where outputText is always choosing e.g. the US decimal style regardless of using the lang attribute or the user language configuration.